# SASS: Catch syntax errors

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sass, rake, rake-task

I have a directory of `.scss` files. I am using `sass --watch src:public` command to watch and compile files, that is working perfectly.

Is there any way to catch whenever there is an error ? Basically instead of going to terminal  i want to produce a 'growl notification' whenever there is an error in compiling sass files.

Otherwise a way to detect change in bash output and just create a growl notification of it. It would be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use sass linter like [sass lint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-lint) to catch **MOST** of them
[image: lint point out issue]

on top of that you can use IDE plugin as well, for example [atom plugin](https://atom.io/packages/linter-sass-lint)

[atom lint error demo](https://atom.io/packages/atom-lint)